# Gradle to 6.6.1 got Could not receive a message from the daemon

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Before I'm using gradle 6.1.1 and springboot 2.2.1 on my windows 10

After upgrade springboot to 2.3.4  Gradle also update to 6.6.1

When run ./gradlew build or other command.
I got  "Could not receive a message from the daemon "

Gradle daemon may improve performance see : [why_the_daemon](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:why_the_daemon)

So I don't want to disabled it.(Do not use org.gradle.daemon=false )

I tried gradle 6.3 that's ok. 6.4 or later not work.

Debug logs

```
> Starting Daemon

ls: 01000431353532002438633231643962382d646664362d343834302d386566362d64646330366462373336363477eacbea35c640d4950f2ea62a2fb2bb0000cfb000000001000000047f0000010037433a5c55736572735c6a6f7631325c2e677261646c655c64
61656d6f6e5c362e362e315c6461656d6f6e2d313535322e6f75742e6c6f67
2020-10-21T11:08:02.992+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: DETACHED
2020-10-21T11:08:02.992+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'Gradle build daemon' finished with exit value 0 (state: DETACHED)
2020-10-21T11:08:02.992+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter] Gradle daemon process is now detached.
2020-10-21T11:08:02.993+0800 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter] An attempt to start the daemon took 2.898 secs.
2020-10-21T11:08:02.993+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector] Started Gradle daemon DaemonStartupInfo{pid=1552, uid=8c21d9b8-dfd6-4840-8ef6-ddc06db73664, address=[77eacbea-35c6
-40d4-950f-2ea62a2fb2bb port:53168, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]], diagnostics={pid=1552, daemonLog=C:\Users\jov12\.gradle\daemon\6.6.1\daemon-1552.out.log}}
2020-10-21T11:08:02.994+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-10-21T11:08:02.994+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2020-10-21T11:08:02.995+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-10-21T11:08:02.995+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Attempting to connect to [77eacbea-35c6-40d4-950f-2ea62a2fb2bb port:53168, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]].
2020-10-21T11:08:02.995+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Trying to connect to address /127.0.0.1.
2020-10-21T11:08:02.998+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Connected to address /127.0.0.1:53168.
2020-10-21T11:08:03.009+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Connected to daemon DaemonInfo{pid=1552, address=[77eacbea-35c6-40d4-950f-2ea62a2fb2bb port:53168, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]],
state=Busy, lastBusy=1603249682985, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=8c21d9b8-dfd6-4840-8ef6-ddc06db73664,javaHome=D:\libs\java,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\jov12\.gradle\daemon,pid=1552,idleTimeout=10800000,prio
rity=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=GBK,-Duser.country=CN,-Duser.language=zh,-Duser.variant]}. Dispatching request Build{id=13ab225
4-7b84-4c2f-ae21-52ade0f571fc, currentDir=D:\works\zhihuicanyinV3}.
2020-10-21T11:08:03.009+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build
2020-10-21T11:08:03.011+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] Problem receiving message to the daemon. Performing 'on failure' operation...
2020-10-21T11:08:03.011+0800 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector] Removing daemon from the registry due to communication failure. Daemon information: DaemonInfo{pid=1552, address=[7
7eacbea-35c6-40d4-950f-2ea62a2fb2bb port:53168, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]], state=Busy, lastBusy=1603249682985, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=8c21d9b8-dfd6-4840-8ef6-ddc06db73664,javaHome=D:\libs\java,daemonReg
istryDir=C:\Users\jov12\.gradle\daemon,pid=1552,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=GBK,-Duser.country=CN,
-Duser.language=zh,-Duser.variant]}
2020-10-21T11:08:03.011+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Storing daemon stop event with timestamp 1603249683011
2020-10-21T11:08:03.012+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-10-21T11:08:03.012+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2020-10-21T11:08:03.014+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-10-21T11:08:03.014+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Removing daemon address: [77eacbea-35c6-40d4-950f-2ea62a2fb2bb port:53168, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]
2020-10-21T11:08:03.015+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-10-21T11:08:03.015+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2020-10-21T11:08:03.017+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-10-21T11:08:03.025+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop
2020-10-21T11:08:03.026+0800 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction]
#############################################################################
   WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING

   Debug level logging will leak security sensitive information!

   https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/logging.html#sec:debug_security
#############################################################################

                      2020-10-21T11:08:03.031+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2020-10-21T11:08:03.031+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2020-10-21T11:08:03.031+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2020-10-21T11:08:03.031+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2020-10-21T11:08:03.032+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not receive a message from the daemon.
2020-10-21T11:08:03.032+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2020-10-21T11:08:03.032+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2020-10-21T11:08:03.032+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
2020-10-21T11:08:03.032+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2020-10-21T11:08:03.032+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anything of interest in the logs in `%UserProfile%\.gradle\daemon\6.6.1`? And if you are using the wrapper scripts, did you regenerate the Gradle wrapper resources by running the `wrapper` task twice?

Comment: @BjørnVester The logs  `020-10-21T11:42:54.117+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Address removed from registry.
Daemon vm is shutting down... The daemon has exited normally or was terminated in response to a user interrupt` showed that  the daemon has exited.And the reason is confusing. I used `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=6.6.1` to upgrade it.And maybe I run twice ,did it caused the Error?